# Получить количество записей по дате

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Подскажите как автоматизировать систему так, чтобы каждый год не писать кучу новых запросов. Идея в том, что в каждом месяце необходимо получать количество заявок. Вот мои запросы за три года:

```html
<?php

$january2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 01');
$february2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 02');
$march2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 03');
$april2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 04');
$may2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 05');
$june2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 06');
$july2019 =  \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 07');
$august2019 =  \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 08');
$september2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 09');
$october2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 10');
$november2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 11');
$december2019 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2019 AND month(updated_at) = 12');

$january2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 01');
$february2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 02');
$march2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 03');
$april2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 04');
$may2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 05');
$june2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 06');
$july2020 =  \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 07');
$august2020 =  \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 08');
$september2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 09');
$october2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 10');
$november2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 11');
$december2020 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2020 AND month(updated_at) = 12');

$january2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 01');
$february2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 02');
$march2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 03');
$april2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 04');
$may2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 05');
$june2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 06');
$july2021 =  \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 07');
$august2021 =  \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 08');
$september2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 09');
$october2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 10');
$november2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 11');
$december2021 = \R::count('tickets', 'year(updated_at) = 2021 AND month(updated_at) = 12');
```

то есть получается, что я каждый год должен писать новый запрос, указав в условиях новые значения

Comment: А что мешает использовать циклы и переменные? Ну и массивы, а не отдельные переменные для результатов. Ещё лучше - один запрос, который получит всё сразу, а затем извлечение нужных записей и полей.

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось получить все сразу одним запросом. Но теперь возникла проблема вывода значений массива через js. В php сделать это очень просто:

```
<?php
foreach ($query as $item) {
    echo $item['year']. ' ' . $item['month'] . ' ' . $item['cnt'];
}
```

Я хочу передать массив $query в js и перебрать этот массив уже в js. Как это сделать?

```html
<?php

$query = \R::getAll("SELECT YEAR(updated_at) AS year, MONTHNAME(updated_at) AS month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tickets GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at), MONTHNAME(updated_at)");
$json = json_encode($query);
?>
<script>
    var arr = JSON.parse('<?=$json;?>');
    console.log(arr);
</script>
```